# me/accounts object not returning pages data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

A analytics script of mine suddenly stopped giving me any data. When i looked inside i found that User object accounts i.e me/accounts is not returning any data. Can anyone shed light to this matter ?. Or experiencing same issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your access token in the [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to ensure you have the `manage_pages` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

Comment: Thanks. It was solved few minutes after i put the question up.